# Ravendb doesn't return right numbers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ravendb, appharbor

I have a very simple code that retrieve some data using aggregate functions.
There is something weird, when I run the project localhost it returns the correct numbers but when I deploy it on appharbor it always return zeros

here is a snapshot of my code

```
        var document = new DocumentStore
        {
            ConnectionStringName = "RAVENHQ_CONNECTION_STRING"
        }; 
        document.Initialize();
        var session = document.OpenSession();
        int start = 0;
        long x = 0, y = 0, z = 0, l = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            var data = session.Query<DailyStat>().Take(1024).Skip(start).ToList();
            if (data.Count == 0)
                break;
            x += data.Sum(x => x.a);
            y += data.Sum(x => x.b);
            start += data.Count;
            z += data.Sum(x => x.c);
            l += data.Sum(x => x.d);
        }
        x /= 1000;
        y /= 1000;
        model.x = x.ToString();
        model.y = y.ToString();
        model.z = z.ToString();
        model.l = l.ToString();
```

when I run the project locally it, raven always return the correct numbers but when I deploy the project on appharbor, the numbers appears as zeros

Answer (score 1):

This code is bad for a lot of reasons. To start with, you shouldn't be doing a loop like that. 
RavenDB limits the number of items you get from the server for a reason, trying to work around that by reading things in a loop is just asking for issues down the road.
In particular, once your data size is big enough, you will get errors from RavenDB because you passed your quota.

Then, you are loading all of those values, just to get the sum. But that is why we have a map/reduce for.